# Loading managed assemblies in a unit test project seems to slow Visual Studio 2010 down

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, reflection, .net-assembly

I am loading multiple managed assemblies in a unit test. The assemblies are from within the solution and not third party, not that it matters. I notice that Visual Studio tends to increase memory consumption after running those tests a few times (usually 10) and slows down overall in terms of build times and responsiveness. This behavior does not surface if those particular unit tests are not run.

The loaded assemblies are used to retrieve embedded types and create instances of ONLY Enum types so there is no chance of code within that assembly causing trouble. I tried a `[ReflectionOnlyLoad]` but that would naturally not allow creation of type instances.

Apparently there is no way to explicitly unload assemblies once loaded unless the entire app domain is unloaded.

My question is, do unit test projects run under the VS process and if so, do these loaded assemblies pile up? I would assume that the unit test context would clean up after itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The loaded assemblies are used to retrieve embedded types and create instances of"

Could be a self modifying code issue

If the asm runs in a non bounded part of the cache it rewrites, and this has a massive hit on the speed of execution for no logical reason to an onlooker

With asm you must keep your dynamic data and your instruction data locked apart

Read/Write dynamic data should be stored outside the block of memory containing the code

http://www.bbcbasic.co.uk/bbcwin/manual/bbcwina.html#cache

The hit is huge, up to 10 times slower

Basically an asm program should be:

allocate 2048k

[dynamic data]

allocate 4096k

[code]

For any flavour of assembly

If you can't do it, learn how, the difference is like night and day